# Folding animation in Both Horizontal / Vertical direction for multiple Images using ImageView

Tags: android, android-layout, animation, android-linearlayout, slideshow

I want make fold animation in both horizontal & vertical and i followed the below link for (DevBytes) for [making folding animation](https://github.com/android/platform_development/blob/master/samples/devbytes/graphics/FoldingLayout/res/layout/activity_fold.xml).However this works for only for single image. How to make it to work for multiple Image Folding one by one (By swiping and autoplay)

`Folding Layout class:`

```
public class FoldingLayout extends ViewGroup {

    public static enum Orientation {
        VERTICAL,
        HORIZONTAL
   }

    private final String FOLDING_VIEW_EXCEPTION_MESSAGE = "Folding Layout can only 1 child at " +
            "most";

    private final float SHADING_ALPHA = 0.8f;
    private final float SHADING_FACTOR = 0.5f;
    private final int DEPTH_CONSTANT = 1500;
    private final int NUM_OF_POLY_POINTS = 8;

    private Rect[] mFoldRectArray;

    private Matrix [] mMatrix;

    private Orientation mOrientation = Orientation.HORIZONTAL;

    private float mAnchorFactor = 0;
    private float mFoldFactor = 0;

    private int mNumberOfFolds = 2;

    private boolean mIsHorizontal = true;

    private int mOriginalWidth = 0;
    private int mOriginalHeight = 0;

    private float mFoldMaxWidth = 0;
    private float mFoldMaxHeight = 0;
    private float mFoldDrawWidth = 0;
    private float mFoldDrawHeight = 0;

    private boolean mIsFoldPrepared = false;
    private boolean mShouldDraw = true;

    private Paint mSolidShadow;
    private Paint mGradientShadow;
    private LinearGradient mShadowLinearGradient;
    private Matrix mShadowGradientMatrix;

    private float [] mSrc;
    private float [] mDst;

    private OnFoldListener mFoldListener;

    private float mPreviousFoldFactor = 0;

    private Bitmap mFullBitmap;
    private Rect mDstRect;

    public FoldingLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public FoldingLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public FoldingLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean addViewInLayout(View child, int index, LayoutParams params,
                                      boolean preventRequestLayout) {
        throwCustomException(getChildCount());
        boolean returnValue = super.addViewInLayout(child, index, params, preventRequestLayout);
        return returnValue;
    }

    @Override
    public void addView(View child, int index, LayoutParams params) {
        throwCustomException(getChildCount());
        super.addView(child, index, params);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        View child = getChildAt(0);
        measureChild(child,widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        setMeasuredDimension(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        View child = getChildAt(0);
        child.layout(0, 0, child.getMeasuredWidth(), child.getMeasuredHeight());
        updateFold();
    }

    private class NumberOfFoldingLayoutChildrenException extends RuntimeException {
        public NumberOfFoldingLayoutChildrenException(String message) {
            super(message);
        }
    }
    private void throwCustomException (int numOfChildViews) {
        if (numOfChildViews == 1) {
            throw new NumberOfFoldingLayoutChildrenException(FOLDING_VIEW_EXCEPTION_MESSAGE);
        }
    }

    public void setFoldListener(OnFoldListener foldListener) {
        mFoldListener = foldListener;
    }

    public void setFoldFactor(float foldFactor) {
        if (foldFactor != mFoldFactor) {
            mFoldFactor = foldFactor;
            calculateMatrices();
            invalidate();
        }
    }

    public void setOrientation(Orientation orientation) {
        if (orientation != mOrientation) {
            mOrientation = orientation;
            updateFold();
        }
    }

    public void setAnchorFactor(float anchorFactor) {
        if (anchorFactor != mAnchorFactor) {
            mAnchorFactor = anchorFactor;
            updateFold();
        }
    }

    public void setNumberOfFolds(int numberOfFolds) {
        if (numberOfFolds != mNumberOfFolds) {
            mNumberOfFolds = numberOfFolds;
            updateFold();
        }
    }

    public float getAnchorFactor() {
        return mAnchorFactor;
    }

    public Orientation getOrientation() {
        return mOrientation;
    }

    public float getFoldFactor() {
        return mFoldFactor;
    }

    public int getNumberOfFolds() {
        return mNumberOfFolds;
    }

    private void updateFold() {
        prepareFold(mOrientation, mAnchorFactor, mNumberOfFolds);
        calculateMatrices();
        invalidate();
    }

    private void prepareFold(Orientation orientation, float anchorFactor, int numberOfFolds) {

        mSrc = new float[NUM_OF_POLY_POINTS];
        mDst = new float[NUM_OF_POLY_POINTS];

        mDstRect = new Rect();

        mFoldFactor = 0;
        mPreviousFoldFactor = 0;

        mIsFoldPrepared = false;

        mSolidShadow = new Paint();
        mGradientShadow = new Paint();

        mOrientation = orientation;
        mIsHorizontal = (orientation == Orientation.HORIZONTAL);

        if (mIsHorizontal) {
            mShadowLinearGradient = new LinearGradient(0, 0, SHADING_FACTOR, 0, Color.BLACK,
                    Color.TRANSPARENT, TileMode.CLAMP);
        } else {
            mShadowLinearGradient = new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, SHADING_FACTOR, Color.BLACK,
                    Color.TRANSPARENT, TileMode.CLAMP);
        }

        mGradientShadow.setStyle(Style.FILL);
        mGradientShadow.setShader(mShadowLinearGradient);
        mShadowGradientMatrix = new Matrix();

        mAnchorFactor = anchorFactor;
        mNumberOfFolds = numberOfFolds;

        mOriginalWidth = getMeasuredWidth();
        mOriginalHeight = getMeasuredHeight();

        mFoldRectArray = new Rect[mNumberOfFolds];
        mMatrix = new Matrix [mNumberOfFolds];

        for (int x = 0; x < mNumberOfFolds; x++) {
            mMatrix[x] = new Matrix();
        }

        int h = mOriginalHeight;
        int w = mOriginalWidth;

        if (FoldingLayoutActivity.IS_JBMR2) {
            mFullBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mFullBitmap);
            getChildAt(0).draw(canvas);
        }

        int delta = Math.round(mIsHorizontal ? ((float) w) / ((float) mNumberOfFolds) :
                ((float) h) /((float) mNumberOfFolds));

        for (int x = 0; x < mNumberOfFolds; x++) {
            if (mIsHorizontal) {
                int deltap = (x + 1) * delta > w ? w - x * delta : delta;
                mFoldRectArray[x] = new Rect(x * delta, 0, x * delta + deltap, h);
            } else {
                int deltap = (x + 1) * delta > h ? h - x * delta : delta;
                mFoldRectArray[x] = new Rect(0, x * delta, w, x * delta + deltap);
            }
        }

        if (mIsHorizontal) {
            mFoldMaxHeight = h;
            mFoldMaxWidth = delta;
        } else {
            mFoldMaxHeight = delta;
            mFoldMaxWidth = w;
        }

        mIsFoldPrepared = true;
    }

    private void calculateMatrices() {

        mShouldDraw = true;

        if (!mIsFoldPrepared) {
            return;
        }

        if (mFoldFactor == 1) {
            mShouldDraw = false;
            return;
        }

        if (mFoldFactor == 0 &&  mPreviousFoldFactor > 0) {
            mFoldListener.onEndFold();
        }

        if (mPreviousFoldFactor == 0 && mFoldFactor > 0) {
            mFoldListener.onStartFold();
        }

        mPreviousFoldFactor = mFoldFactor;

        for (int x = 0; x < mNumberOfFolds; x++) {
            mMatrix[x].reset();
        }

        float cTranslationFactor = 1 - mFoldFactor;

        float translatedDistance = mIsHorizontal ? mOriginalWidth * cTranslationFactor :
                mOriginalHeight * cTranslationFactor;

        float translatedDistancePerFold = Math.round(translatedDistance / mNumberOfFolds);

        mFoldDrawWidth = mFoldMaxWidth < translatedDistancePerFold ?
                translatedDistancePerFold : mFoldMaxWidth;
        mFoldDrawHeight = mFoldMaxHeight < translatedDistancePerFold ?
                translatedDistancePerFold : mFoldMaxHeight;

        float translatedDistanceFoldSquared = translatedDistancePerFold * translatedDistancePerFold;

        float depth = mIsHorizontal ?
                (float)Math.sqrt((double)(mFoldDrawWidth * mFoldDrawWidth -
                        translatedDistanceFoldSquared)) :
                (float)Math.sqrt((double)(mFoldDrawHeight * mFoldDrawHeight -
                        translatedDistanceFoldSquared));

        float scaleFactor = DEPTH_CONSTANT / (DEPTH_CONSTANT + depth);

        float scaledWidth, scaledHeight, bottomScaledPoint, topScaledPoint, rightScaledPoint,
                leftScaledPoint;

        if (mIsHorizontal) {
            scaledWidth = mFoldDrawWidth * cTranslationFactor;
            scaledHeight = mFoldDrawHeight * scaleFactor;
        } else {
            scaledWidth = mFoldDrawWidth * scaleFactor;
            scaledHeight = mFoldDrawHeight * cTranslationFactor;
        }

        topScaledPoint = (mFoldDrawHeight - scaledHeight) / 2.0f;
        bottomScaledPoint = topScaledPoint + scaledHeight;

        leftScaledPoint = (mFoldDrawWidth - scaledWidth) / 2.0f;
        rightScaledPoint = leftScaledPoint + scaledWidth;

        float anchorPoint = mIsHorizontal ? mAnchorFactor * mOriginalWidth :
                mAnchorFactor * mOriginalHeight;

        /* The fold along which the anchor point is located. */
        float midFold = mIsHorizontal ? (anchorPoint / mFoldDrawWidth) : anchorPoint /
                mFoldDrawHeight;

        mSrc[0] = 0;
        mSrc[1] = 0;
        mSrc[2] = 0;
        mSrc[3] = mFoldDrawHeight;
        mSrc[4] = mFoldDrawWidth;
        mSrc[5] = 0;
        mSrc[6] = mFoldDrawWidth;
        mSrc[7] = mFoldDrawHeight;

        for (int x = 0; x < mNumberOfFolds; x++) {

            boolean isEven = (x % 2 == 0);

            if (mIsHorizontal) {
                mDst[0] = (anchorPoint > x * mFoldDrawWidth) ? anchorPoint + (x - midFold) *
                        scaledWidth : anchorPoint - (midFold - x) * scaledWidth;
                mDst[1] = isEven ? 0 : topScaledPoint;
                mDst[2] = mDst[0];
                mDst[3] = isEven ? mFoldDrawHeight: bottomScaledPoint;
                mDst[4] = (anchorPoint > (x + 1) * mFoldDrawWidth) ? anchorPoint + (x + 1 - midFold)
                        * scaledWidth : anchorPoint - (midFold - x - 1) * scaledWidth;
                mDst[5] = isEven ? topScaledPoint : 0;
                mDst[6] = mDst[4];
                mDst[7] = isEven ? bottomScaledPoint : mFoldDrawHeight;

            } else {
                mDst[0] = isEven ? 0 : leftScaledPoint;
                mDst[1] = (anchorPoint > x * mFoldDrawHeight) ? anchorPoint + (x - midFold) *
                        scaledHeight : anchorPoint - (midFold - x) * scaledHeight;
                mDst[2] = isEven ? leftScaledPoint: 0;
                mDst[3] = (anchorPoint > (x + 1) * mFoldDrawHeight) ? anchorPoint + (x + 1 -
                        midFold) * scaledHeight : anchorPoint - (midFold - x - 1) * scaledHeight;
                mDst[4] = isEven ? mFoldDrawWidth : rightScaledPoint;
                mDst[5] = mDst[1];
                mDst[6] = isEven ? rightScaledPoint : mFoldDrawWidth;
                mDst[7] = mDst[3];
            }
            for (int y = 0; y < 8; y ++) {
                mDst[y] = Math.round(mDst[y]);
            }


        int alpha = (int) (mFoldFactor * 255 * SHADING_ALPHA);

        mSolidShadow.setColor(Color.argb(alpha, 0, 0, 0));

        if (mIsHorizontal) {
            mShadowGradientMatrix.setScale(mFoldDrawWidth, 1);
            mShadowLinearGradient.setLocalMatrix(mShadowGradientMatrix);
        } else {
            mShadowGradientMatrix.setScale(1, mFoldDrawHeight);
            mShadowLinearGradient.setLocalMatrix(mShadowGradientMatrix);
        }
        mGradientShadow.setShader(mShadowLinearGradient);

        mGradientShadow.setAlpha(alpha);
    }

    @Override
    protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        if (!mIsFoldPrepared || mFoldFactor == 0) {
            super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
            return;
        }

        if (!mShouldDraw) {
            return;
        }


        for (int x = 0; x < mNumberOfFolds; x++) {

            src = mFoldRectArray[x];

            canvas.concat(mMatrix[x]);
            if (FoldingLayoutActivity.IS_JBMR2) {
                mDstRect.set(0, 0, src.width(), src.height());
                canvas.drawBitmap(mFullBitmap, src, mDstRect, null);
            } else {

                canvas.clipRect(0, 0, src.right - src.left, src.bottom - src.top);

                if (mIsHorizontal) {
                    canvas.translate(-src.left, 0);
                } else {
                    canvas.translate(0, -src.top);
                }

                super.dispatchDraw(canvas);

                if (mIsHorizontal) {
                    canvas.translate(src.left, 0);
                } else {
                    canvas.translate(0, src.top);
                }
            }

            if (x % 2 == 0) {
                canvas.drawRect(0, 0, mFoldDrawWidth, mFoldDrawHeight, mSolidShadow);
            } else {
                canvas.drawRect(0, 0, mFoldDrawWidth, mFoldDrawHeight, mGradientShadow);
            }

            canvas.restore();
        }
    }

}
```

// onFoldListener

```
public interface OnFoldListener {
    public void onStartFold();
    public void onEndFold();
}
```

// FoldingLayoutActivity

```
public class FoldingLayoutActivity extends Activity {

    private final int ANTIALIAS_PADDING = 1;

    private final int FOLD_ANIMATION_DURATION = 1000;
    static final boolean IS_JBMR2 = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2;

    private FoldingLayout mFoldLayout;
    private SeekBar mAnchorSeekBar;
    private Orientation mOrientation = Orientation.HORIZONTAL;

    private int mTranslation = 0;
    private int mNumberOfFolds = 2;
    private int mParentPositionY = -1;
    private int mTouchSlop = -1;

    private float mAnchorFactor = 0;

    private boolean mDidLoadSpinner = true;
    private boolean mDidNotStartScroll = true;

    private boolean mIsCameraFeed = false;
    private boolean mIsSepiaOn = true;

    private GestureDetector mScrollGestureDetector;
    private ItemSelectedListener mItemSelectedListener;

    private Camera mCamera;
    private TextureView mTextureView;
    private ImageView mImageView;

    private Paint mSepiaPaint;
    private Paint mDefaultPaint;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fold);

        mImageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image_view);
        mImageView.setPadding(ANTIALIAS_PADDING, ANTIALIAS_PADDING, ANTIALIAS_PADDING,
                ANTIALIAS_PADDING);
        mImageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        mImageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image));

        mTextureView = new TextureView(this);
        mTextureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(mSurfaceTextureListener);

        mAnchorSeekBar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.anchor_seek_bar);
        mFoldLayout = (FoldingLayout)findViewById(R.id.fold_view);
        mFoldLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        mFoldLayout.setFoldListener(mOnFoldListener);

        mTouchSlop = ViewConfiguration.get(this).getScaledTouchSlop();

        mAnchorSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(mSeekBarChangeListener);

        mScrollGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this, new ScrollGestureDetector());
        mItemSelectedListener = new ItemSelectedListener();

        mDefaultPaint = new Paint();
        mSepiaPaint = new Paint();

        ColorMatrix m1 = new ColorMatrix();
        ColorMatrix m2 = new ColorMatrix();
        m1.setSaturation(0);
        m2.setScale(1f, .95f, .82f, 1.0f);
        m1.setConcat(m2, m1);
        mSepiaPaint.setColorFilter(new ColorMatrixColorFilter(m1));
    }

    private OnFoldListener mOnFoldListener =
            new OnFoldListener() {
        @Override
        public void onStartFold() {
            if (mIsSepiaOn) {
                setSepiaLayer(mFoldLayout.getChildAt(0), true);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onEndFold() {
            setSepiaLayer(mFoldLayout.getChildAt(0), false);
        }
    };

    private void setSepiaLayer (View view, boolean isSepiaLayerOn) {
        if (!IS_JBMR2) {
            if (isSepiaLayerOn) {
                view.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
                view.setLayerPaint(mSepiaPaint);
            } else {
                view.setLayerPaint(mDefaultPaint);
            }
        }
    }

    private TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener mSurfaceTextureListener = new TextureView
            .SurfaceTextureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture, int i, int i2) {
            mCamera = Camera.open();

            if (mCamera == null && Camera.getNumberOfCameras() > 1) {
                mCamera = mCamera.open(Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT);
            }

            if (mCamera == null) {
                return;
            }

            try {
                mCamera.setPreviewTexture(surfaceTexture);
                mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
                mCamera.startPreview();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture, int i, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture) {
            if (mCamera != null) {
                mCamera.stopPreview();
                mCamera.release();
            }
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture) {

        }
    };

    private SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener mSeekBarChangeListener = new SeekBar
            .OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            mTranslation = 0;
            mAnchorFactor = ((float)mAnchorSeekBar.getProgress())/100.0f;
            mFoldLayout.setAnchorFactor(mAnchorFactor);
        }
    };

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        if (IS_JBMR2) {
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.fold_with_bug, menu);
        } else {
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.fold, menu);
        }
        Spinner s = (Spinner) menu.findItem(R.id.num_of_folds).getActionView();
        s.setOnItemSelectedListener(mItemSelectedListener);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged (boolean hasFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);

        int[] loc = new int[2];
        mFoldLayout.getLocationOnScreen(loc);
        mParentPositionY = loc[1];
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent me) {
        return mScrollGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(me);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected (MenuItem item) {
        switch(item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.animate_fold:
                animateFold();
                break;
            case R.id.toggle_orientation:
                mOrientation = (mOrientation == Orientation.HORIZONTAL) ? Orientation.VERTICAL :
                        Orientation.HORIZONTAL;
                item.setTitle((mOrientation == Orientation.HORIZONTAL) ? R.string.vertical :
                R.string.horizontal);
                mTranslation = 0;
                mFoldLayout.setOrientation(mOrientation);
                break;
            case R.id.camera_feed:
                mIsCameraFeed = !mIsCameraFeed;
                item.setTitle(mIsCameraFeed ? R.string.static_image : R.string.camera_feed);
                item.setChecked(mIsCameraFeed);
                if (mIsCameraFeed) {
                    mFoldLayout.removeView(mImageView);
                    mFoldLayout.addView(mTextureView, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                            mFoldLayout.getWidth(), mFoldLayout.getHeight()));
                } else {
                    mFoldLayout.removeView(mTextureView);
                    mFoldLayout.addView(mImageView, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                            mFoldLayout.getWidth(), mFoldLayout.getHeight()));
                }
                mTranslation = 0;
                break;
            case R.id.sepia:
                mIsSepiaOn = !mIsSepiaOn;
                item.setChecked(!mIsSepiaOn);
                if (mIsSepiaOn && mFoldLayout.getFoldFactor() != 0) {
                    setSepiaLayer(mFoldLayout.getChildAt(0), true);
                } else {
                    setSepiaLayer(mFoldLayout.getChildAt(0), false);
                }
                break;
            default:
               break;

        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void animateFold ()
    {
        float foldFactor = mFoldLayout.getFoldFactor();

        ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mFoldLayout, "foldFactor", foldFactor, 1);
        animator.setRepeatMode(ValueAnimator.REVERSE);
        animator.setRepeatCount(1);
        animator.setDuration(FOLD_ANIMATION_DURATION);
        animator.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
        animator.start();
    }

    private class ItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
            mNumberOfFolds = Integer.parseInt(parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString());
            if (mDidLoadSpinner) {
                mDidLoadSpinner = false;
            } else {
                mTranslation = 0;
                mFoldLayout.setNumberOfFolds(mNumberOfFolds);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        }
    }

    private class ScrollGestureDetector extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onDown (MotionEvent e) {
            mDidNotStartScroll = true;
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
            int touchSlop = 0;
            float factor;
            if (mOrientation == Orientation.VERTICAL) {
                factor = Math.abs((float)(mTranslation) / (float)(mFoldLayout.getHeight()));

                if (e2.getY() - mParentPositionY <= mFoldLayout.getHeight()
                        && e2.getY() - mParentPositionY >= 0) {
                    if ((e2.getY() - mParentPositionY) > mFoldLayout.getHeight() * mAnchorFactor) {
                        mTranslation -= (int)distanceY;
                        touchSlop = distanceY < 0 ? -mTouchSlop : mTouchSlop;
                    } else {
                        mTranslation += (int)distanceY;
                        touchSlop = distanceY < 0 ? mTouchSlop : -mTouchSlop;
                    }
                    mTranslation = mDidNotStartScroll ? mTranslation + touchSlop : mTranslation;

                    if (mTranslation < -mFoldLayout.getHeight()) {
                        mTranslation = -mFoldLayout.getHeight();
                    }
                }
            } else {
                factor = Math.abs(((float)mTranslation) / ((float) mFoldLayout.getWidth()));

                if (e2.getRawX() > mFoldLayout.getWidth() * mAnchorFactor) {
                    mTranslation -= (int)distanceX;
                    touchSlop = distanceX < 0 ? -mTouchSlop : mTouchSlop;
                } else {
                    mTranslation += (int)distanceX;
                    touchSlop = distanceX < 0 ? mTouchSlop : -mTouchSlop;
                }
                mTranslation = mDidNotStartScroll ? mTranslation + touchSlop : mTranslation;

                if (mTranslation < -mFoldLayout.getWidth()) {
                    mTranslation = -mFoldLayout.getWidth();
                }
            }

            mDidNotStartScroll = false;

            if (mTranslation > 0) {
                mTranslation = 0;
            }

            mFoldLayout.setFoldFactor(factor);

            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

//activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.example.android.foldinglayout.FoldingLayout
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/fold_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp">

        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image_view"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

        </com.example.android.foldinglayout.FoldingLayout>

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/anchor_seek_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:max="100"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: If anyone have build this view, than share with me , My email id is anil.anil.gamgwar@gmail.com