# Folding animation for multiple images like slide show

Tags: android, android-animation, slideshow

Folding animation for multiple images, for one layout is for vertical and another is for horizontal, any one direction, i followed this [this example](https://github.com/android/platform_development/tree/master/samples/devbytes/graphics/FoldingLayout) it is working perfectly for only one image, and it support only for one image, my question is how to make it to support for multiple images. i referred this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35440286/folding-animation-in-both-horizontal-vertical-direction-for-multiple-images-us) like the same but no solution found, can any one suggest a solution.

Comment: If anyone have build this view, than share with me , My email id is anil.anil.gamgwar@gmail.com